# Using static keyword to prohibit the utilization of stack memory

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, stack, code-analysis

I have to process arrays with huge size and due to some constraints, I cannot use dynamic memory allocation. But, huge arrays means burning down the stack memory. To avoid this, I have declared my class objects as "static", intending them to end up in BSS segment.

This is my sample template class:

```
template<int size1, int size2>
class foo {

   public:
    unsigned char arr[size1*size2];
    int total;

    foo();
    ~foo();

    //copy constructor
    foo(const foo &bar)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size1*size2;++i)
        {
            arr[i] = bar.arr[i];
        }
    }

    //assignment operator
    foo& operator=(const foo& bar)
    {
        if(this == &bar)
        {
            return *this; 
        }

        for(int i=0; i<size1*size2;++i)
        {
            arr[i] = bar.arr[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void newcopy(void *ptr);

};//end of class foo

//Default constructor
template<int size1, int size2>
inline foo<size1, size2>::foo(){
   total = size1*size2;
}

//Destructor
template<int size1, int size2>
foo<size1, size2>::~foo()
{
    printf("Destructor is being executed\n");
}

//Member function
template<int size1, int size2>
inline void foo<size1, size2>::newcopy(void *ptr)
{
    unsigned char *local = (unsigned char *)ptr;
    for(int i=0; i<size1*size2;++i)
    {
      arr[i] = (unsigned char)(local[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my sample main function:

```
#define val1 2500
#define val2 3000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    static foo<val1,val2> bar1;
    static foo<val1,val2> bar2;
    static foo<val1,val2> temp;

    /*  bar1 = fill_data<val1, val2>(128);
        bar2 = fill_data<val1, val2>(255);  */

    //filling data into objects
    for(int i =0; i<val1*val2;++i)
    {
        bar1.arr[i] = 128;
        bar2.arr[i] = 255;
    }

    //simple swap
    temp.newcopy(bar1.arr);
    bar1.newcopy(bar2.arr);
    bar2.newcopy(temp.arr);

    //printing a few values after swap
    for(int i =0; i<10;++i)
    {
         printf("%d %d\n", bar1.arr[i], bar2.arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And as expected, the objects declared as static are showing up in BSS segment.

Output of 'size' command for the code with static keyword:

```
text  data  bss      dec

2801  640  22500112 22503249
```

Output of 'size' command for the code without static keyword:

```
text  data  bss      dec
2366  640   8        2998
```

If I execute this, the program runs fine.

Now, I have created a separate function for the data filling part, to move it  out of the main, as below:

```
template<int size1, int size2>
foo<size1, size2> fill_data(int thresh){

    foo<size1, size2> in;
    for(int i =0; i<size1*size2;++i)
    {
        in.arr[i] = thresh;
    }
    return in;
 }
```

When I call this function (see the commented block in the main function), I get a segmentation fault. (I don't get a segfault if the val1 & val2 combined value doesn't cross 5000)

When I debug it, it doesn't even enter main!

Is the segfault because of stack overflow?

But, of what I see in this code, there are neither large variables nor deep function calls nor any recursions to blow up the stack.

Am I missing something here? Can someone please explain me the reason for this segfault, in detail?

I use RHEL6 64 bit.

Comment: The large variable is right there at the first line of `fill_data`.  Consider passing a reference to the object to fill, instead of creating a new one and returning it (return values also get stored on the stack if they don't fit in processor registers).

Comment: @BenVoigt I think he's expecting it to optimize the copy, using the caller's memory for `in`.

Comment: Strange, I'd expect there to be more memory in the heap (dynamic memory) than in the global area (for statics), a.k.a. BSS.

Comment: You may want to consider using an OS API to allocate large blocks of memory.

Comment: @BenVoigt Unfortunately, I cannot alter the API of `fill_data` function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The code is targeted for kind of an embedded device which doesn't support dynamic memory or system calls.

Comment: @Goutham: Why not?  Your question says you created it.  Bottom line is that a function returning by value is absolutely useless for values which do not fit on the stack.  There is absolutely nothing you can do to be able to call that function with the existing signature.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Makes sense! Now, not for solving the issue, but in a learning perspective, I experimented with using malloc, instead of declaring an array, for `arr` in the `foo` class and declared the objects in the main function without 'static' keyword. This should also cause a segfault, because, in the `fill_data` function, there is still the same huge array declared and returned, correct?  But, it runs fine! Why is that?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain why you cannot use heap allocation (`new`, `malloc`, `mmap`...). On a Linux system, this is really weird (and probably wrong). Also, do you care about multi-threading?.

Answer (score 0):

**You are wrong in avoiding any heap allocation** (`new`, `malloc`, [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), and you should explain why you need to do that (consider perhaps having your own [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)). Most C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) are using some, and manage their internal memory with [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (and standard containers, e.g. [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), accept some allocator template argument). Read about the C++ [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Consider [using](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) smart pointers. So `arr` should be some pointer field (perhaps a smart one), not a huge array field.

If your code is for some embedded device, it needs a large amount of memory, and you should consider implementing your own `malloc` & `free` (or find some suitable implementation of them), that `new` & `delete` could use.

But your `fill_data` is returning a *huge* data structure (of more than 2500*3000 bytes). If you study the [x86-64 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI), you'll find out that it uses a temporary memory zone on the stack (and the ABI of your embedded processor probably does likewise). With a huge data structure, you blow out the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), and you get a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (that is a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).

As a rule of thumb, your call stack is limited to a few megabytes (see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...), and generally less on embedded systems. There is some way to increase that limit (on Linux, but probably not on your embedded system). Be careful with multi-threaded applications.